# Import and export bookmarks in Skim

Tags: macos, skim

How can I import my [Skim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skim_%28software%29) bookmarks so that they can be restored on a clean installation of OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're stored in `~/Library/Preferences/net.sourceforge.skim-app.skim.bookmarks.plist`. You should quit the application before restoring a copy of the plist.